# Design Data Processing Solution in Azure

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

We have large amounts of `CSV` files which arrive to a dedicated drive (e.g. D:) on a daily basis. Then, a set of `SSIS` packages will pick up those files, performs transformations on them, and then ingest the result into several tables in a database. Logging and error handling do also exist.

As we are experimenting a possible move to the cloud (`Azure` in particular), we went for a lift and shift scenario at the beginning. In this approach, we simply deployed the same `SSIS` packages into `Azure SQL Server`, created `Azure Data Factory` `ADF` pipelines, and run those packages from there.

We would like to re-factor our solution to replace `SSIS` packages, with cloud-native services of `Azure`.

My questions would be:

1. Based on the scenario explained in the first paragraph, is this considered as a Batch Processing scenario ? Does `Azure Batch Service` fit in as potential service to use ? Or it would be more efficient to use `Azure DataBricks` with `ADF` ?
2. Below is the solution environment and main tasks on-premises. I would like to have a comparison between what we do in `SSIS`, and the counterpart in `Azure` world:

| Item | On-Premise World | Azure World |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Storage to receive CSV files | Normal Disk Drive D:\ | ? |
| CSV File Processing | SSIS -> Data Flow -> Script Component | ? |
| Ingest to Destination Table | SSIS -> Data Flow -> OLE DB Destination | ? |
| Custom Scripting | Script Task & Script Component | ? |
| Database | SQL Server | ? |

3. Recommendations/best practices/approaches used in similar migration projects ?

Comment: What types of custom transforms do you do in the custom script component?

Comment: @wBob to name few: 1- Run SQL query to select a batch of files we want to process, 2- loop through the files to read the content from the physical path, 3- produce a stream out of the content being read, 4- Adding new output, based on values of specific column values. The script is written in VB.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Azure Data Factory for the ETL part. (In fact, it even support your existing SSIS packages).

I don't think Azure Batch is the right choice in this case, but you can use it. Azure Batch is more used for intensive compute process e.g. rendering 3d arts

Answer (score 0):

Azure Synapse Analytics is probably a good fit for this.  You could stand up the individual products (eg SQL DB, Azure Data Factory etc) but you get easier integration between the components with Synapse:

| Item | On-Premise World | Azure World |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Storage to receive CSV files | Normal Disk Drive D:\ | Azure Data Lake Gen 2 |
| CSV File Processing | SSIS -> Data Flow -> Script Component | Polybase |
| Ingest to Destination Table | SSIS -> Data Flow -> OLE DB Destination | CTAS |
| Custom Scripting | Script Task & Script Component | Synapse Notebooks |
| Database | SQL Server | Dedicated SQL Pools |

**Components**

- Azure Data Lake Gen 2 - when you provision a Synapse workspace you will have the option to provision data lake storage if you don't have
- Polybase - or external tables, allows you to create virtual tables over your .csv files stored in the lake for easy reading
- CTAS - or `CREATE TABLE AS`.  Use CTAS to materialise your csv files from the data lake into physical tables in your database
- Synapse Notebooks - use Synapse Notebooks for very custom processing, basically things you can't already do easily with SQL or Synapse Pipelines.  These even support c# so you could do more of a lift-and-shift for certain pieces of code although some customisation would definitely be required
- dedicated SQL pools - scalable MPP database with pause and resume.

If you have < 1TB you should consider looking at Azure SQL DB and ADF standalone instead.